# ¿Como configurar springboot para Azure?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, azure, microservices

Tengo deployado en Azure un microservicio en Springboot y una base de datos SQL server, localmente me funciona perfecto la conexión, pero cuando le hago un POST, falla la conexión con el siguiente mensaje:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-06-13T05:15:34.434+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection",
    "path": "/login"
}
```

Estoy usando Hibernate para mi conexion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían dar una mano de como configurar spring boot o la base de datos para que me tome la conexión? Otra cosa que se me ocurre, es que el Firewall de la base de datos me este bloqueando la conexión del servidor, pero lo puse sin Firewall (aunque a veces me sigue pidiendo la IP).

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, considera sustituir la imagen por el texto respectivo del archivo `application.properties` evitando el uso de imagenes.

Answer (score 1):

Pude "arreglarlo", era una configuración en el Firewall de la base de datos.
Tuve que poner "Si" en la parte de "Permitir que los servicios y recursos de Azure accedan a este servidor":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Muchas gracias, buenas noches!